# Is there a good way to load images one by one?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this code, that takes imgs file names from DB, and simply displays them in the grid.
Trouble is, the client added wide huge pics, that have some loading time. 
For some reason, the browser loads the images in a random order, or maybe the smaller ones first.

**I want the browser to load the images one by one in the order they appear in the code, the top one, then the on bellow etc.**

one remark - the page has some other images too, it's not the only grid.
another remark - should i consider combining a loading gif?

```html
<?php
$result = mFiles($id);                  
if ($result) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $theFile=$row['img2'];
  }
?>

<div style="float:left;width:100%;">
  <img src="images/upload/files/<?php echo($theFile); ?>" />
</div>
```

thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: You should use jquery lazy load. check https://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the ***Lazy-Load*** plugin for JQuery

Add the reference:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Modify your code like,

```
<div style="float:left;width:100%;">
    <img class="lazy" src="img/loading.gif" data-original="images/upload/files/<?php echo($theFile); ?>" />
</div>
```

Then use `$("img.lazy").lazyload();` to lazyload all images in the page with class "lazy".

If you don't want a loading image to show up, just create a 1x1 blank image, and that should do the trick.

Reference: [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload)

P.S. The order in which image is retrieved depends upon how its stored in your DB.

Hope this helps. :)